# pd.read_excel randomly does not work, giving BadZipFile

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that runs weekly, and as of this week it failed with BadZipFile when trying to read an excel file with pandas. No changes have been made to the script and the dependency versions have not changed. Python 3.7, pandas 1.3.5, openpyxl 3.0.10. Here is the stack trace:

```
 df = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=1)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
 return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 364, in read_excel
 io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1192, in __init__
 content_or_path=path_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1090, in inspect_excel_format
 zf = zipfile.ZipFile(stream) # type: ignore[arg-type]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1258, in __init__
 self._RealGetContents()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1325, in _RealGetContents
 raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")zipfile.BadZipFile:
 File is not a zip file
```

EDIT - I've retried the operation a few times with the same result. I can open, read, and edit the file manually, but for some reason the script is getting an error. I've tried opening the file with openpyxl and xlrd - get the same result with both.

Comment: Something might be changing in your environment. Perhaps the file is being written and is not complete? The table of contents of a zip file is at the end, so that would certainly affect the ability to identify the file. I would suggest you write an exception handler that triggers on the failure to report some information on the file you're trying to read. Does it exist? What are the permissions? What is the size of the file? When was it last modified? Things to determine if you've caught it in flight. You could also retry the operation.

Comment: Have you investigated after a failure to determine that the failed file is, indeed, readable and valid format? What is creating the file? Has anything changed upstream like the version of application creating it?

Comment: `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing well formed XML files. If you get a ZIP error it means the *file* is corrupt. Where does this file come from and what does it actually contain? Is it a real `xlsx` file or eg a CSV or HTML table with a fake extension? Many web sites fake Excel exports by generating a CSV or HTML table with an `xlsx` extension and an Excel MIME type.

Comment: `I can open, read, and edit the file manually` that doesn't mean much. How do you open and edit the file, how is it saved? Excel won't be fooled by the fake extension for example and will load a CSV as a text file using the user's locale for import settings (field and decimal separator, date format). It will warn you that this isn't an actual Excel file but won't stop you from saving.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when I change the source file to a csv, the script can now open the file but the formatting is messed up. If I open the csv version in excel it complains that there could be data loss and recommends changing it to excel format.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd party in charge of uploading the file canceled their automation which created the script, and they completely rewrote it from scratch and started it again. This ended up solving my problem, so it is likely that somehow the file was actually corrupted even though I could open it and the data looked correct.